# Protocol error when loading an image, web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web

I'm writing a web application in asp.net core. I have a web server setup that i am hosting all my images on. I'm trying to load images into cards but i'm getting a "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". If I enter the url for my images into Chrome the picture shows without any issues, I just get the error in my web app. I have created a trusted certificate for my app, I have tried both http and https in the image url but can't get it to work. Here is an example of my url

https://myservername:8099/resources/Division/foods.jpg

I have the image url saved to a database field and am trying to set the card as below

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <div class="card h-100">
        <a asp-controller="ServiceAreas" asp-action="ServiceAreasView" class="" asp-route-DivisionId="@item.DivisionId">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="@item.ImagePath" />
            <h4 class="card-title text-center">@item.DivisionName</h4>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what else to look for or try, anyone else have similar issue ?

Comment: Have you tried <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">?

Comment: I have added that tag in previosly, but still have the same issue. I've checked the read and write permissions on the server, that too is all fine. Not sure what could be causing this.